# Is it possible to create a ternary operator for this statement in PHP?

Tags: php, ternary-operator

```
    function integer($str)
    {
        if(preg_match('/[^0-9]/', $str)) 
        { 
           return FALSE;
        }

        else
        {
           return $str;
        }
    }
```

Is it possible to create a ternary operator for this statement in PHP?

Comment: If this isn't a learning exercise, I'd recommend the built in `is_int` function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php

Comment: @SimpleCoder That only checks the type, not the content -- `is_int("4")` returns false.

Comment: @lonesomeday: Thanks, I meant `is_numeric`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes:

```
function integer($str) {
  return (preg_match('/[^0-9]/', $str) ? false : $str);
}
```

Comment: `$str = ""` should return `""` ?

Comment: @salathe - just addressing OPs question not critiquing his code/process.

Answer (score 3):

You should use [`ctype_digit`](http://php.net/ctype_digit) for that:

```
function integer($str) {
    return ctype_digit($str) ? $str : false;
}
```

Or use [`filter_var`](http://php.net/filter_var) with [`FILTER_VALIDATE_INT`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php):

```
function integer($str) {
    return filter_var($str, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array(
        'options' => array('min_range' => 0),
        'flags' => FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_OCTAL
    ));
}
```

Comment: `filter_var` can optionally be configured to allow min and max values, so you could also limit it to positive integers only.

Comment: @Gordon: Can one specify `min_range` only?

Comment: @Gordon, re. octal, see the `FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_OCTAL` flag.

Comment: @salathe: I think not allowing octal numbers is expected, normally.

Comment: @nikic, a reasonable assumption to make. I was just reminding Gordon (and readers) that the filter *can* optionally allow octal integers.

Comment: @Gordon: How nice `ctype_digit` looks now, compared to the `filter_var` variant...

Comment: @nikic it's shorter, but technically `filter_var` does much more than just checking the string for numbers. I guess it depends what the OP is after.